# Create derived control at runtime cause assertion

Tags: mfc, runtime, dynamically-generated, derived-class

I am trying to create a control at run-time, but it causes assertion, and I don't know what's causing it.  The control I am using is the Tree ComboBox Control from this link:  https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/187762/Tree-ComboBox-Control

I added the code to register the class as follow:

```
CTreeComboBox::CTreeComboBox()
    ...
{
    ...

    RegisterWindowClass();
}

CTreeComboBox::~CTreeComboBox()
{
    m_BrushAlert.DeleteObject();
}


BOOL CTreeComboBox::RegisterWindowClass()
{
    WNDCLASS wndcls;
    HINSTANCE hInst = AfxGetInstanceHandle();

    if (!(::GetClassInfo(hInst, _T("TreeComboBox"), &wndcls)))
    {
        wndcls.style = CS_DBLCLKS | CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
        wndcls.lpfnWndProc = ::DefWindowProc;
        wndcls.cbClsExtra = wndcls.cbWndExtra = 0;
        wndcls.hInstance = hInst;
        wndcls.hIcon = NULL;
        wndcls.hCursor = AfxGetApp()->LoadStandardCursor(IDC_ARROW);
        wndcls.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_3DFACE + 1);
        wndcls.lpszMenuName = NULL;
        wndcls.lpszClassName = _T("TreeComboBox");

        if (!AfxRegisterClass(&wndcls))
        {
            AfxThrowResourceException();
            return FALSE;
        }
    }

    return TRUE;
}
```

I tried to create the control at run-time using the following code in the test program:

```
BOOL CTestComboBoxDlg::OnInitDialog()
{
    ...

    m_ComboBox2.CreateEx(WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE, _T("TreeComboBox"), _T(""), WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | CBS_DROPDOWNLIST | WS_VSCROLL | WS_TABSTOP,
        CRect(0, 0, 100, 50), this, 100000, NULL);

    return TRUE;  // return TRUE  unless you set the focus to a control
}
```

I also tried creating the control using a button click event thinking that I should let the GUI finish initializing, but the same error occur:

```
void CTestComboBoxDlg::OnBnClickedButton1()
{
    m_ComboBox2.CreateEx(WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE, _T("TreeComboBox"), _T(""), WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | CBS_DROPDOWNLIST | WS_VSCROLL | WS_TABSTOP,
        CRect(0, 0, 100, 50), this, 100000, NULL);
}
```

When I run the program, it stopped at the file dbgrptt.cpp at the following line:

```
     __try
            {
                if (_CRT_ASSERT == nRptType && _InterlockedIncrement(&_crtAssertBusy) > 0)
                {
                    /* use only 'safe' functions -- must not assert in here! */

                    _ERRCHECK(_itoa_s(nLine, szLineMessage, DBGRPT_MAX_MSG, 10));

                    OutputDebugStringA("Second Chance Assertion Failed: File ");
                    OutputDebugStringA(szFile ? szFile : "<file unknown>");
                    OutputDebugStringA(", Line ");
                    OutputDebugStringA(szLineMessage);
                    OutputDebugStringA("\n");

  It stop here===>  _CrtDbgBreak();
                    retval=-1;
                    __leave;
                }
```

The program run fine if I create the control manually using the Visual Studio GUI editor, so I am not sure what's wrong.  Can you help me figure out how to create this control at run-time?

Note: change the statement: `TRACE1(_T("Item selected: %s\n"), GetItemText(hItem));` to `TRACE(_T("Item selected: %s\n"), GetItemText(hItem));` in the file ComboTreeCtrlExt.cpp if you if you want to run the code and are using MFC

Comment: _"When I run the program, it stopped at the file dbgrptt.cpp"_ -- The top of the call stack is usually not that relevant. To make this question more valuable, the *full* call stack should be included.

Answer (score 1):

To answer my own question.  Move the following code from the `CTreeComboBox::PreSubclassWindow()` to the `CTreeComboBox::OnCreate()`

```
CRect rect(0, 0, 0, 0);
DWORD dwStyle =  WS_POPUP | WS_BORDER;
CWnd* pWnd = &m_Tree;
pWnd->CreateEx(0, WC_TREEVIEW, NULL, dwStyle, rect, GetParent(), 0, NULL);
m_Tree.Init(this);

GetClientRect(rect);
SetDroppedWidth(rect.Width());
SetDroppedHeight(m_nDroppedHeight);

dwStyle = CBS_DROPDOWNLIST & GetStyle();
ASSERT(CBS_DROPDOWNLIST == dwStyle);
```